# How quickly view many symbolized fields of the same shapefile in ArcGIS pro or other software

Tags: shapefile, symbology, time-series

I have a shapefile that represents a grid to a numerical flow model. There can be 100's of fields in the shapefile that represent different values in each polygon of the multipolygon. I'm trying to come up with a way to rapidly cycle through many symbologies of each field so that I can view each one like you would cycle through time series on a netcdf file.